# Python 2.7 posting, and getting result from web site

Tags: python-2.7, web, web-scraping

I appreciate the help in advance. I am trying to write a python script that posts an IP address to a site referenced below, and get the results printed out in the terminal or file, and then read the file immediately after.

Here is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import requests


IP = raw_input("Enter IP address here: ")

Alert_URL = 'http://www.blacklistalert.org'


def submit_form():
    """Submit a form"""
    payload = IP

    # make a get request
    resp = requests.get(Alert_URL)
    print "Response to GET request: %s" % resp.content

    # send POST request
    resp = requests.post(Alert_URL, payload)
    print "Headers from a POST request response: %s" % resp.headers
    # print "HTML Response: %s" %resp.read()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    submit_form()
```

The site has section to input IP addresses on the web page, and inspecting the site I found lines to input as follows:

```
<form method=POST onsubmit="document.forms[0].submit.disabled='true';">
IP or Domain <input onclick="this.value='';" name=q value=11.11.154.23>
```

I would like to post an IP address that I want to check to the site using the input section above somehow. For instance using raw_input to post into the 'value=' section, and get the result.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the  `PHPSESSID` and post:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


ip = raw_input("Enter IP address here: ")

data = {"q":  ip} # ip goes here
url = "http://www.blacklistalert.org/"

with requests.Session() as s:
    # get the page first to parse
    soup = BeautifulSoup(s.get(url).content)
    # extract and add the PHPSESSID
    PHPSESSID = soup.select_one("input[name=PHPSESSID]")["value"]
    data["PHPSESSID"] = PHPSESSID
    # finally post
    res = s.post(url, data=data)
    print(res)
    print(res.content)
```